# How to handle dynamic module loading in a Vite-Based React Application?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, vite, commonjs

I'm migrating a React frontend site from Create React App to Vite and facing an issue with dynamic component loading. In CRA, I used a combination of `remote-component.config.js` and `new Function('require', 'module', 'exports', code)` to load components from a text string.

This functionality breaks when switching to Vite because the packages I try to load use a commonJs style react: require('react') which does not work with Vite. Even if use a Vite plugin like `viteCommonjs` this will change the require statements into import statements but still breaks loading the function because the imports are now async.

So my question is: What is the best way to dynamically load a (commonJS or ES6) module from string within my application.

I have looked into [vite-plugin-federation](https://github.com/originjs/vite-plugin-federation) but that would require the remote component to be loaded from file..

Comment: Where does the string contained in `code` comes from?

Comment: @Valentin from my database, it's contains a react component and it's build using webpack ( or rollup ) earlier.